# autotools dosnt create Makefile.im or Makefile on new computer

Tags: linux, makefile, autotools

So i have a problem compiling my software project on my new computer. Unfortunately my old computer is broken and i have to use the new one.
My Problem is, that i cant build my software project the way it worked on the old one. The old on runs with Kubuntu, the new one Arch.
The setting is an existing project and i try to make a tool library for it. In the past i just created a folder and enter the foldername in the Makefile.am. In this folder i put the source codes and the Makefile.am from my backup.
If i run

```
autoreconf -fi
./configure
```

it doesn't create the Makefile.im nor the Makefile. I also tried to run

```
aclocal
autoheader
libtoolize
automake --add-missing
autoconf
```

But it doesn't create the Makefiels. For troubleshooting i tried to add "-W all" to see the problems but there is no output with this argument.
The Makefile.am works on my old computer but not on the new on. But i am able to compile the whole software without my additions and the autotools work like expected.

I think the Problem is located by automake because the step from Makefile.am to Makefile.im is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Solution by myself. I forgot to edit the configure.ac file. So the configure Script was not up to date and ignored the new directory. I leave this here for every other Person who runs in this problem.